# Проведены обыски или обыска"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, жаргон

Как правильно: "проведены обыски" или "проведены обыска"?

Comment: Дк "ы", или "и"? Какое правило действует?

Answer (score 1):

Литературная норма — "Обыски".

Answer (score 0):

Именительный падеж, множественное число - обыски.